# Preference for tin or iron in the reduction of nitrobenzene

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, organic-reduction, nitro-compounds

My NCERT book(Class 12) said the following for reduction of nitrobenzene using $\ce{Sn/HCl}$ and $\ce{Fe/HCl}$ :
[image]
Now, I have been following [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/14749/reaction-mechanism-for-reduction-of-nitrobenzene-to-aniline-in-catalytic-and-aci?r=SearchResults) mechanism for this particular reduction, and it seems to me that the metal is getting oxidized to +2 state wherever it is shown that 2 electrons are being transferred. If that is the case, then:

•Why is $\ce{Fe + HCl}$ being preferred?

•Because I looked it up on [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tin(II)_chloride) and it says that $\ce{SnCl2}$ also gets hydrolysed to liberate $\ce{HCl}$ as follows:
$\ce{SnCl2 (aq) + H2O (l) ⇌ Sn(OH)Cl (s) + HCl (aq)}$

Or have I interpreted the mechanism incorrectly?

Comment: Probably preferred for cost reasons, iron being cheaper than tin

Comment: @Waylander But the way the book has stated it,it seems that this regeneration of HCl takes place only with Fe. So is there a problem with the yield in case of Sn+HCl?

Comment: I can see no problem with your. My guess is that the preference the authors express is for Fe/HCl over catalytic hydrogenation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The book's reasoning is correct. Fe/HCl gives $\ce{FeCl2}$ on reaction and it gets hydrolyzed by steam vapors to produces more hydrochloric acid and hydrogen to push the reaction forward thus making the reaction self-sustaining to produce more aniline from nitrobenzene.

$$\ce{Fe + 2HCl ->[160°C,CH3OH] FeCl2 + H2}$$

$$\ce{3FeCl2 + 4H2O(steam) ->[Hydrolysis] Fe3O4 + 6HCl + H2 }$$

whereas $\ce{SnCl2}$ gives $\ce{Sn(OH)Cl}$ and 1 mole of hydrogen chloride which is insufficient and it gets exhausted after sometime.

The other thing is cost factor as @Waylander said. Iron scrap is way cheaper than tin.

Both Sn/HCl and Fe/HCl reduction([Bechamp reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bechamp_reduction)) is replaced by catalytic hydrogenation due to the latter being more efficient and more productive in industial production. Fe/HCl reduction is now an academic interest and is studied as a route to produce iron oxide based pigments.